# Trying to display an Image from gallery to a dynamically created ImageView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to display an Image which I get from the gallery. I can't call `setImageBitmap` like one would normally do. Is that because the ImageView is not created yet?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


//LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
ArrayList<ImageView> listItemImg=new ArrayList<>();

//DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LIST VIEW
ArrayAdapter<ImageView> adapter;

//RECORDING HOW MANY TIMES THE BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED
int clickCounter=0;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (mListView == null) {
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.picsListView);
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_layout, R.id.picImageView, listItemImg);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

This the method that is called when the button is clicked.

```
public void addStuff(View view) {

    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    gallery.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(gallery, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

}


//METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION


protected ListView getListView() {
    if (mListView == null) {
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.picsListView);
    }
    return mListView;
}

protected void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);

            //This is the ImageView in which I'm trying to display the selected Image.
            listItemImg.set(clickCounter, bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        clickCounter++;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


}
```

Sorry if the question is too basic. I couldn't find any example of use nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a **wrong adapter** to the ListView. An ArrayAdapter can only place the corresponding **String** object from the given array to **TextViews** if it is used directly.

In this case you need to make a **custom adapter by extending ArrayAdapter** (or any of the adapters) and ovrride the [getView(int, View, ViewGroup)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method.

[Here](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-adapters-adapterviews/) is a good tutorial about Adapters and AdapterViews.